# How to update visible ScrollablePositionedList items

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a ScrollablePositionedList and I want to update the background color of every visible list item during a touch event. I am able to change the background color of the selected item in the list but finding it difficult to access/update every other item on list.

Here is what I have so far,

```
body: SizedBox(
      height: 100,
      child: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () {
            var position = itemPositionsListener.itemPositions.value.first.index;
            print(position);
            //trigger leaving and use own data
            Navigator.pop(context, false);

            //we need to return a future
            return Future.value(false);
          },
          child: ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              initialScrollIndex: startPosition,
              itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
              itemPositionsListener: itemPositionsListener,
              itemCount: 14,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                  MonthTile(getWidth(), months[index],(MonthTile tile){
                    itemScrollController.scrollTo(
                        index: getPosition(index),
                        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                        curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic);
                    //  }
                  })))
  ),
```

What I'm basically aiming for is to have the selected item revert to its original color when another item is selected. I guess my question is, is there widget one can use to accomplish this?.

Comment: You can create a variable int currentlyTap; and change it to the number you tap. And then add to every item color: currentlyTap==index ? tapColor : normalColor.

Comment: This is a good idea. I tried it but I have the same issue. setState doesn't propagate the changes to all list items. That is they don't change back once another item is selected.

Comment: Your comment let me down the right path! I ended up doing as you suggested but also wrapping my Scrollable list in a ValueListenableBuilder and passed the ValueNotified to each list item. Thanks!.